# Hybrid property expression with JOIN

Tags: python, peewee

I'm fairly new to `peewee`, but have some strong background on SQLAlchemy (and all the vices that come with it). I'm trying to create a custom hybrid expression that correlates to a third (or even N) table. I'll try to demonstrate in an example (non-tested) code:

```py
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database


class Person(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(column_name="person_id")
    name = CharField(max_length=255, column_name="person_name")
    username = CharField(max_length=255, column_name="person_username")



class PersonTree(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(column_name="person_tree_id")
    name = CharField(max_length=255, column_name="person_tree_name")
    code = CharField(max_length=255, column_name="person_tree_code")

    person = ForeignKeyField(
        column_name="person_id",
        model=Person,
        field="id",
        backref="tree",
    )


class Article(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(column_name="article_id")
    name = CharField(max_length=255, column_name="article_name")

    branch = ForeignKeyField(
        column_name="person_tree_id",
        model=PersonTree,
        field="id",
        backref="articles",
    )

    @hybrid_property
    def username(self):
        """
        This gives me the possibility to grab the direct username of an article
        """
        return self.branch.person.username

    @username.expression
    def username(cls):
        """
        What if I wanted to do: Article.query().where(Article.username == "john_doe") ?
        """
        pass
```

With the `username` `hybrid_property` on `Article`, I can get the `username` of the `Person` related to an `Article` using the `PersonTree` as a correlation, so far so good, but ... What if I wanted to "create a shortcut" to query all `Articles` created by the `"john_doe"` `Person` username, without declaring the `JOIN`s every time I make the query and without relying on `.filter(branch__person__username="john_doe")`? I know it's possible with SA (to a great extent), but I'm finding this hard to accomplish with `peewee`.

Just for clarification, here's the SQL I hope to be able to construct:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    article a
    JOIN person_tree pt ON a.person_tree_id = pt.person_tree_id
    JOIN person p ON pt.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE
    p.username = 'john_doe';
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hybrid properties can be used to allow an attribute to be expressed as a property of a model instance or as a scalar computation in a SQL query.

What you're trying to do, which is add multiple joins and stuff via the property, is not possible using hybrid properties.

> What if I wanted to "create a shortcut" to query all Articles created by the "john_doe" Person username

Just add a normal method:

```
@classmethod
def by_username(cls, username):
    return (Article
            .select(Article, PersonTree, Person)
            .join(PersonTree)
            .join(Person)
            .where(Person.name == username))
```

Comment: Got it. I thought it was possible to make some sort of a "scalar reference" via any of the selectable methods from `peewee`, such as `cls.branch.person.code` or `Person.select(Person.username).join(PersonTree).join(Article).where(Article.id == cls.id)`. That would be a neat feature to have, though :-)